# h2, prepared statement and identity resulting in a no natively generated identify value error

Tags: java, orm, h2

I have a an entity with an Id column as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "vw")
public class School {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
```

A liquibase configuration setting up the schema in h2 as follows

```
CREATE TABLE school
(
  id  BIGINT IDENTITY (1, 1),
```

And a prepared statement as part of TriggerAdapter in order to write to a view.

public class UpdatableViewSchool extends TriggerAdapter {
    private PreparedStatement prepDelete, prepInsert;

```
@Override
public void init(Connection conn, String schemaName, String triggerName,
                 String tableName, boolean before, int type) throws SQLException {
    prepDelete = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM school WHERE id = ?");
    prepInsert = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO school " +
            " (school, class, first, second, third, fourth, " +
            " fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth, tenth ) " +
            " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    super.init(conn, schemaName, triggerName, tableName, before, type);
}

@Override
public void fire(Connection conn, ResultSet oldRow, ResultSet newRow)
        throws SQLException {
    if (oldRow != null && oldRow.next()) {
        prepDelete.setInt(1, oldRow.getInt(1));
        prepDelete.execute();
    }
    if (newRow != null && newRow.next()) {
        prepInsert.setInt(1, newRow.getInt(2)); // school
        prepInsert.setString(2, newRow.getString(4)); // class
        prepInsert.setInt(3, newRow.getInt(5)); // first
```

I am getting an error

```
The database returned no natively generated identity value.
```

Shouldn't an IDENTITY column in h2 be an auto incrementing column?